# Can I replace the avatar used in the three.js example morphtargets_human with my own avatar?

Tags: animation, three.js, blender, avatar

I am trying to use the three.js example [morphtargets_human](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_human.html) and replace the avatar used with my own avatar. I studied the files used in this example and I cannot see why I cannot replace it. I created an [avatar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NxBaFriZVFMURjRFhHUDBVWjA/view?usp=sharing) with morph targets (1 morph target + default) and skeleton. I exported the morph targets as morph animation and the skeleton as skeletal animation (It seems that morph targets and skeletal animation are required for this to work). When I open the javascript file on the browser, I can only see the dat gui controls, but the avatar is not displayed. How can I make this work?

Additional files: [umich_ucs.js](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/UCS/umich_ucs.js),
[UCSCharacter.js](http://threejs.org/examples/js/UCSCharacter.js), [UCS_config.json](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/UCS_config.json), [Detector.js](http://threejs.org/examples/js/Detector.js), [dat.gui.min.js](http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js), [three.min.js](http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js), [OrbitControls.js](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js)

jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n4da3b2r/11/)

```
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        var container;

        var camera, scene;
        var renderer;

        var mesh;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        var gui, skinConfig, morphConfig;

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );
            camera.position.set( 2000, 5000, 5000 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // LIGHTS

            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
            light.position.set( 0, 140, 500 );
            light.position.multiplyScalar( 1.1 );
            light.color.setHSL( 0.6, 0.075, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            //

            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
            light.position.set( 0, -1, 0 );
            scene.add( light );

            // RENDERER

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            // CHARACTER

            character = new THREE.UCSCharacter();
            character.onLoadComplete = function() {
                console.log( "Load Complete" );
                console.log( character.numSkins + " skins and " + character.numMorphs + " morphtargets loaded." );
                gui = new dat.GUI();
                setupSkinsGUI();
                setupMorphsGUI();
                gui.width = 300;
                gui.open();
            }

            var loader = new THREE.XHRLoader();
            loader.load("http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/UCS_config.json", function ( text ) {

                var config = JSON.parse( text );
                character.loadParts( config );
                scene.add( character.root );

            } );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.center.set( 0, 3000, 0);

            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

        }

        function setupSkinsGUI() {

            var skinGui = gui.addFolder( "Skins" );

            skinConfig = {
                wireframe: false
            };

            var skinCallback = function( index ) {
                return function () {
                    character.setSkin( index );
                };
            }

            for ( var i = 0; i < character.numSkins; i++ ) {
                var name = character.skins[ i ].name;
                skinConfig[ name ] = skinCallback( i );
            }

            for ( var i = 0; i < character.numSkins; i++ ) {
                skinGui.add( skinConfig, character.skins[i].name );
            }

            skinGui.open();

        }

        function setupMorphsGUI() {

            var morphGui = gui.addFolder( "Morphs" );

            morphConfig = {
            };

            var morphCallback = function( index ) {
                return function () {
                    character.updateMorphs( morphConfig );
                }
            }

            for ( var i = 0; i < character.numMorphs; i ++ ) {
                var morphName = character.morphs[ i ];
                morphConfig[ morphName ] = 0;
            }

            for ( var i = 0; i < character.numMorphs; i ++ ) {
                morphGui.add( morphConfig, character.morphs[ i ] ).min( 0 ).max( 100 ).onChange( morphCallback( i ) );
            }

            morphGui.open();

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 10;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 10;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            controls.update();

            render();

        }

        function render() {

            var delta = 0.75 * clock.getDelta();

            // update skinning

            THREE.AnimationHandler.update( delta );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Comment: add source code please

Comment: I have just edited my post with the files I used.

Comment: are these your source code (the altered code)? or the three.js sample code? i think it is the latter, your sample code is needed

Comment: I put a link with the word "avatar" on third line. That's my avatar code (a js file). The rest is three.js sample code.

Comment: hmm, ok, i suggest add a jsfiddle example where the problem can be studied with the all the necessary files included (your avatar also)

Comment: I don't know how to attach my json file using jsffidle.

Comment: either include it literaly as is in the javascript window of jsfiddle, or add it in a public cloud and link from there

Comment: Also, there are some additional files that I can't find online without giving me error, such as: UCSCharacter.js, Detector.js and OrbitControls.js.

Comment: I edited my post with the updated link of the jsfiddle code.

Comment: jsfiddle gives this error TypeError: container is null
https://fiddle.jshell.net/n4da3b2r/10/show/ 105

Comment: // RENDERER

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    **container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );**

Comment: I don't know what it means.

Comment: it means the container in which the rest items are added, is not initialised in the code, so when it reaches the part where the Three.js renderer is appended to container, it throws an error, try to fix it

Comment: I changed the word "container" to "document.body" and it's not giving me that error anymore.

Comment: new error TypeError: `THREE.UCSCharacter is not a constructor`
https://fiddle.jshell.net/n4da3b2r/11/show/ 109

Comment: use firebug or chrome dev tools (or whatever browser you use) and fix all these so the actual problem can be studied

Comment: Ok. How can I upload a js file inside another js file using jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out. The problem was scaling. My avatar was too big, so I could not see it displayed on browser.